# What the ImageNet Vid policy over evaluation of frames with zero object inside

Tags: object-detection, imagenet

Ι am trying to evaluate my **video object detection** module and I am using InageNet VID dataset for this purpose. At some point I am facing the case to evaluate a frame containing zero objects. Meaning there are no ground truth bboxes in this frame (this is fine since we are talking about video object detection).

Since, the module I am using expected at least 1 bbox to be present I was wondering what's the official treatment for these case by ImageNet. I found [this description](http://image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2017/#vid) which obviously not exhaustive one may provide some point in ImageNet site which states:

> The evaluation metric is the same as for the objct detection task,
>   meaning objects which are not annotated will be penalized, as will
>   duplicate detections (two annotations for the same object instance).

(sic; typo is from the original text)

Which does not mention the above case scenario. Since this is a simple description I am not sure it covers every edge case. Normally in single image object detection this is not an issues since evaluation samples always contain some object. But in this case does this mean I should ignore those frames for example altogether?

Also, checking [this repository](https://github.com/rafaelpadilla/Object-Detection-Metrics#true-positive-false-positive-false-negative-and-true-negative) about object detection metric (which is super analytic by the way) the no gt case seems to fall into the general scenario about *False Positive (FP)*. In this case *Intersection* would be 0 (since no gt bbox exists) and *Union* would be just a non zero number equal to the FP bbox and so, `IoU = 0`.

So, how does the official ImageNet deal with these cases? I am not interested in what is reasonable choice here, just the official version.

Answer (score 1):

I have just looked through the ImageNet VID 2015 evaluation code, which I got from the evaluation kit from [UNC](http://bvisionweb1.cs.unc.edu/ilsvrc2015/download-videos-3j16.php).

The evaluation deals with precision and recall, and so needs to calculate TP, FP and FN for every GT box/detection pair or instance. The IoU calculation is used purely to determine whether a valid detection has taken place.

For frames with no GT boxes, and no detections: As we are not recording true negatives these make no difference to the calculation.

For frames with no GT boxes, but some detections: These false positives are captured for each frame on line 231 of `eval_vid_detections.m`:

```
    if kmax > 0
        tp(j) = 1;
        gt_detected(kmax) = 1;
    else
        fp(j) = 1;
    end
```

For frames with GT boxes, but no detections: These GT boxes are counted when the GT data is first loaded on line 79: `num_pos_per_class(c) = num_pos_per_class(c) + 1;`. This is later used when calculating the recall on line 266: `recall{c}=(tp/num_pos_per_class(c))';`

So, if your frame contains no detections and no GT boxes, you can safely ignore it.

As an aside, note that the per instance detection threshold is set like this:

```
    thr = (gt_w.*gt_h)./((gt_w+pixelTolerance).*(gt_h+pixelTolerance));
    gt_obj_thr{i} = min(defaultIOUthr,thr);
```

where `pixelTolerance = 10`. This gives a bit of a boost to small objects.

Answer (score 0):

What about the case where there is a missing annotation for an object which should have had a GT annotation ?

For example `ILSVRC2015_val_00000001/000266.JPEG` clearly has a turtle (in fact up until `000265.JPEG` all the frames has the corresponding annotation of turtle) but the corresponding annotation file `ILSVRC2015_val_00000001/000266.xml` doesn't have any annotation.

In my analysis, there are `4046` frames out of `176126` in validation dataset which have missing GT annotation. Most of these frames have no GT annotation despite containing an object which belongs to one of the `30` categories of ImageNetVID.